# CFBuilder not stopping on breakpoints

Tags: eclipse, debugging, coldfusion, remote-debugging, coldfusionbuilder

Since this question...

[Eclipse doesn't stop at breakpoints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388192/eclipse-doesnt-stop-at-breakpoints)

...deals with eclipse itself and CFBuilder is eclipse based, I thought it might be helpful.  One of the comments there mentioned stopping the server and redeploying the app :(

**My question is this:**  if CFBuilder (I'm using v 1.0) doesn't stop on breakpoints, or if it gets a li'l question mark icon over the breakpoint when it's set, how do I fix this Without Restarting The Server.  Restarting fixes the issue about 95% of the time, but it takes a few minutes (slow/old machine).

Is there a way to redeploy w/o restarting, or another quick fix so that my workflow doesn't get interrupted?  It's maddening to have to restart the server just to debug my code.

For reference, this is remote debugging, since it's coming from the server on the wings of an HTTP request.

**Some additional info**
The Project menu has the following grayed out for me:

- Build All
- Build Project
- Clean...
- and Select Working Set... (under Build Working Set)

Comment: are you sure you have setup the RDS correctly?

Comment: @Henry I'm able to debug most of the time successfully, it's just that once in a while (especially after changing code) it will fail.  But to answer your question, no I'm not sure.  I'm also not sure how to troubleshoot that bit if it is wonky. :)

Comment: Out of curiosity, is this a common experience for CF devs, or is it 'just me' that's having this issue?  :)  (I know sometimes my teammates also have the same issue - just wondering if it's something in our particular setup or if this is standard operating procedure.

Comment: havne't used breakpoints for quite a while.  CFDUMP and CFABORT is the more common workflow for most I believe.

Comment: I'd be very curious to know if lots of cf devs are using cfdump/cfabort over the CFBuilder debugger with remote debugging.  Halting execution + a dump seems very limited (especially if it's a hassle to get back to where you were for the next guess if you aren't sure what's gone wrong yet).

Answer (score 1):

I was having this problem.  My ColdFusion project is stored in D:\work\myproject; and I have created a link (using MKLINK) in C:\ColdFusion10\cfusion\wwwroot\myproject.  When you create the ColdFusion project make sure that the project directory is C:\ColdFusion10\cfusion\wwwroot\myproject and not D:\work\myproject.  The path to the project is /myproject.

Comment: Did this solve the problem for you?  I'm assuming so :)  Just a note if anyone's trying this for a project set up in an 'external' location.  I deleted the project (in CFBuilder - NOT opting to delete the files on the filesystem) and imported an existing project.  It gave me grief because I'd used mklink w/o using the \D option.  When I did that CFBuilder could see it ok (although I had to manually type in the path because it picked up the path the sym link was to, which buys you nothing, I think).

Comment: I've tried it and now the debugger connects but won't stop on any breakpoints, even after restarting the CF server itself.  Maybe I misunderstood.  I'd had my project in something like D:\work\myproject and was thinking that you're suggesting to create the link in C:\ColdFusion10\cfusion\wwwroot\myproject.  Are you saying that having it linked instead of having the project actually reside in the wwwroot folder is the cause or the solution to the problem?  Sorry for the confusion :)

Comment: I changed it back to having the project directory be the actual folder the project is in and now it will at least stop on breakpoints.  Is there something else I missed that allowed it to work for you when you had the project directory as the link?

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting the Debugging Server. Login to your ColdFusion Administrator and go to Debugging & Logging > Debugger Settings where you will find a Restart button. If it is a consistent problem then you might have something else going on.

Comment: I'll give it a shot next time the symptom occurs.  If that works I'll definitely accept.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try refreshing your project after code change and before debugging.