# Line debugging Lucee app

Tags: debugging, coldfusion, lucee

CFBuilder has its own built-in line debugger, and our team finds great benefit in the advantages FusionDebug brings.

Due to the aging Eclipse foundation of CFBuilder, we've recently switched to doing most of our editing in Atom, only going back to CFB to debug.

Is there a way to do line debugging (breakpoints, step into/over, watch expressions, etc.) in Lucee without using CFBuilder at all?  I'd love to ditch it altogether.

*Edit: I'm aware of FusionReactor's browser-based debugger, but I know that's both paid and part of a large tool suite.  Sadly, my budget tops out at $0/month. I'm looking for something that, like Lucee, is free.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sometimes we don't want to accept "no" as an answer, but this time I think the answer is "no".

Comment: Le Sigh.  I will accept my fate :)  On that note, Henry's comment on a related question a while ago makes me wonder if that's really how CF development is done (and if so, if it's still done that way today): http://stackoverflow.com/q/10233847/749227  It seems like a very expensive workflow.

Answer (score 0):

Most of my debugging is done in SQL Server.

I do everything with stored procedures.
So I write my query in sql server and debug it using ssms:

```
IF OBJECT_ID ('usr.where_id', 'P' ) IS NOT NULL 
DROP PROC usr.where_id
GO
create proc usr.where_id
(@id int
) as
declare @categoryid int = 0
select @categoryid=categoryid
from usr
where id=@id

select field1,field2
from usr
where id=@id
exec category.where_categoryid @categoryid
go
```

And to test:

```
exec usr.where_id 1234
```

I then call the stored procedure using a syntax like the following:

```
storedproc procedure='usr.where_id' {
    procparam value=url.id;
    procresult name='usr';
    procresult resultset=2 name='category';
}
```

And then I loop through the procresults. The ability to return multiple resultsets is key to why I use stored procedures.

Comment: I use ssms extensively too.  Mostly I'm wondering about line debugging ColdFusion code itself.