# Eclipse Neon Debug mode is not working

Tags: eclipse, debugging

I was using Juno and debug mode is working fine in that. But in Neon as shown in attached, is not detecting the debug mode.
I have made several attempts as below.

1. I'm Sure I'm running on Debug mode
2. Break points are not skipped
3. Clean the project and executed again
4. Restarted the eclipse and machine
5. Executed the code with a comment in console, for making sure the code line is executing.
   -- What else I can try to make this working
   [image]

**UPDATE**
I'm getting error as 
(https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=468908)
[image]

Comment: What does "Executed the code with a comment in console" mean? Was this screenshot taken during a debug session?

Comment: @nitind I was trying whether the mentioned break point code is working or not.

Comment: @nitind Is there any other settings to enable the break points in Eclipse Neon?