# Can't start debugging / Shift from VStudioC# to Java Eclipse

Tags: android, debugging

Please, help me to find out what's wrong.
Android App, under Eclipse, SDK is setup, Android 2.2
Configuration is ok, Emulator is Ok. When run Debug, it shows some references to Libs which are not in MY source code.
I'm stuck, it confuses me really and badly.

It doesn't react to breakpoints, skip them, and the breakpoints are crosslined and of blue color, which is looking like they're not activated.

Hard to be adapted after Visual Studio.

I've recorded video:

http://www.youtube.com/embed/WyRyVrrmXAE?hl=ru&fs=1

Also, path to android-sdk is correct.

Comment: You've got a NullPointerException - check your LogCat window for all the details.

Comment: Can you tell why breakpoints are crosslined? they should be blue round button, not crosslined, can you see that?

Comment: Yeah, I could see that - don't know why. Mine have ticks on them. Thought it might be because you were adding them after debugging had started but its not that. Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1370868/eclipse-debugger-doesnt-stop-at-breakpoint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the "Skip All Breakpoints" option enabled. It's a toolbar button in the Breakpoints view (panel) that is a toggle button; most likely you inadvertently turned it on and didn't notice.
If you bring the Breakpoints view the front, you'll see the" crossed-out dot" button on its toolbar and can click it to turn that off; then your breakpoints will hit as expected.

[image]