# Breakpoints broken in EClipse

Tags: eclipse, debugging

I am running EClipse Juno Java EE and I put a break point on some of my methods both the methods in the classes and methods like "Before" in the Junit class. Then I run the JUnit I have and it passes green But does not catch any of my breakpoints. 
What are some settings in EClipse maybe? that I should double check to make sure everything is set up right? it doesn't catch my breakpoints.
P.S: Ok I wan't in "Debug" perspective but now I switched to "Debug" perspective but still not hitting the break point.

Comment: Which JDK are you using?

Comment: If it's before update 15 you just need to upgrade your JDK.  See the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1370992/1288

Comment: Ok thanks Bill, but how can I know which update do I have? sorry for stupid questions.

Comment: that's wht I have: java version "1.6.0_35"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_35-b10)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.10-b01, mixed mode)

Comment: so do I have update 35? so it isn't that bug fix ?

Comment: Yes, that means it's update 35.  I'd probably download a Java 7 JDK at this point anyway, but it looks like your problem might be something else.

Answer (score 1):

Ah found the issue... I was using "Run As" ... but I should be using "Debug As".