# Undebuggable thread (breakpoints ineffective) in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, breakpoints

I have a handler on the "Low Memory Detector" thread, and although Eclipse lets me set breakpoints in the code in my handler, it runs through the breakpoint-tagged lines without pausing the thread.  (Breakpoints in other threads are working normally.)  Is this expected behavior?  Is there a trick to aid debugging in this situation?

(This thread is for notifications from the MXMemoryBean.)

Comment: I'm running Eclipse Helios (3.6), in case that makes a difference.

Comment: What's your JDK version? It might be related to a bug in [JDK6u 14](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1370868/eclipse-debugger-doesnt-stop-at-breakpoint).

Comment: That linked question sounds just like my problem, but I think I may be upgraded past the fix ---- java version "1.6.0_39" / 
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_39-b04-442-10M4008) / 
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.14-b01-442, mixed mode)

Comment: Trying -XX:+UseParallelGC did not help the problem.  (This appears to be one of the bug reports for the issue referenced above: http://bugs.sun.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=6862295 )