# Eclipse stuck on same line when debugging

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging

Sorry if this has already been answered but I can't find anything...
So I am making android app, and when I try to debug and enters in break point, I press resume and it stays on the same line, it blinks like it is going ot the next line, but it stays on the same line, the same when I press Step over. So I can only debug by removing the current breakpoint and then resuming and it goes to the next one, and still the same...
What could be wrong?

Comment: You're probably in a loop.

Comment: no its not a loop code

Answer (score 0):

When you press "Resume", the app goes back to running as normal until it hits another break point (or in your case, hit's the same break point again).

If you want to step through line by line then you need to press "Step Over" to move to the next line.

Comment: Post the code it's happening in and indicate where your break point is

Comment: not that it matters, but for example here
@Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_sub_categories);
  dh = new DataHelper(getApplicationContext());
  parentId = (Long) getIntent().getExtras().get("parentId");
  initializeListViews();
 }

there is breakpoint on every line

Comment: Does this happen when you try and debug any project? If so it sounds like a problem with eclipse itself, and you may be best off downloading and re-installing.

Comment: Then I suggest downloading eclipse again and re-installing (I assume you've already tried just closing and then restarting eclipse?).

Comment: yes, restart doesnt work.... but why a whole new install, I'll have to download all the apis and stuff again, isnt there just some folder of Eclipse I can clean?

Comment: If there is, I would not know which one. A new install ensures you are starting with a clean slate. I assume you've searched to see if anyone else has had similar problems? Have a read through this [discussion here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1370868/eclipse-debugger-doesnt-stop-at-breakpoint). It may give some clues.

Comment: In that discussion, for some people removing all break points and then cleaning the project seems to fix some problems. It's worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem but on PHP development. I mean that the whole debugger "seemed" to work but the main code window was not updating with the appropriate file / line unless I would right click on debug view "Lookup source".

This thread helped me fix the issue: https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/823451/

(I ended up installing a recent nightly build of PDT)

Hope this can help other people finding this thread here.

Olivier