# Eclipse not stopping at breakpoints while debugging

Tags: eclipse, debugging

I'm debugging a program which works with multiple matrix and the breakpoints are not working. When I start the debugging, a pointer appears indicating where in the code the program stopped. The thing is, this pointer doesn't appear in a line with a breackpoint, it shows up in wherever it suits it and the worst thing is that enters a function which gives me the values of the coordinates in the matrix so you can imagine that I'm in a loop that is hard to get out.

I have tried using the "Step Return" to get out of that function but, as a loop, I always end there again. Also, the "Ignore breakpoints" is not activated.

Have I some debugging option activaded by mistake? thank you for your time

Comment: Your source code does not match the bytecode - i.e. you are trying to debug a different version than the one you have.

Comment: I made a Clear+Build and it's still happening... If I activate the "Ignore Breakpoint" button the debugging doesn't stop in those lines without breakpoints either, invisible breakpoint?

Comment: Maybe you accidentally have a trigger point that has to be reached first to activate all other breakpoints. See [here](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.7/jdt.php#triggers-for-breakpoints) and [my video](https://youtu.be/Y0-cO9wZj6w?t=7m11s). You talk about debugging a Java application, right?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Eclipse - debugger doesn't stop at breakpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1370868/eclipse-debugger-doesnt-stop-at-breakpoint)

Comment: I'm ashamed of my error. I didn't check in the "Brakpoints" section of the UI and there were the invisible breakpoints that were messing with me.  Thank you all for the answers!

Answer (score 0):

I didn't check the "Breakpoints" window in the "Debugging" prespective thus not seeing that there were some kind of breakpoints that I didn't know about and I don't have any idea appeared. I removed them and I could debug as usual.